# Capture Qt widget as an image file

Tags: qt, opengl, jpeg

I'm working with QGLWidget (Qt widget for OpenGL) and want to be able to capture the screen displayed by the widget as JPEG files. How can I achieve this? Is there a function that return what is currently displayed on the widget as an image?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Normally with OpenGL, you would read from the framebuffer using  the [`glReadPixels()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) function. This will put the framebuffer contents into a buffer that you have allocated. You then need a function that will convert this to JPEG.

However, as you are using `QGLWidget`, you can use its [`grabFrameBuffer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#grabFrameBuffer) method to obtain the frame buffer contents as a `QImage` object. This is probably the better way to go. You can grab the framebuffer contents, then use [`QImage::save()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#save) to save to a file.

If you move to Qt 5's `QOpenGLWidget`, you'll find it has a similar 
[`grabFrameBuffer()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#grabFramebuffer) method.

Comment: The two mentioned methods are QImage QGLWidget::grabFrameBuffer ( bool withAlpha = false ) and bool QImage::save ( const QString & fileName, const char * format = 0, int quality = -1 ) const.

Answer (score 10):

```
QImage img(mywidget.size());
QPainter painter(&img);
mywidget.render(&painter);
img.save("/some/file.jpg");
```

Comment: "If format is 0, QImage will attempt to guess the format by looking at fileName's suffix."  - http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qimage.html#save

Comment: It's also important to have `widget->setVisible(true)` if your widget has children (and is not already visible on the screen).

Comment: Note that using `setVisible()` doesn't work very nicely at all if you are using a `QWidget` for off-screen rendering since the widget will be displayed briefly.

Comment: Note that I added (above or below) my answer which improves on this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simplest way to save widget as an image, working on Qt 5:

```
QString file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save as...", "name", "PNG (*.png);; BMP (*.bmp);;TIFF (*.tiff *.tif);; JPEG (*.jpg *.jpeg)");
ui->myWidget->grab().save(file);
```

Comment: unfortunately this apparently (for me) does not capture QGLWidgets contained within the grabbed widget.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the very simple incantation `QPixmap::grabWindow( m_widget->winId() ).save( "/some/file.jpg" )`

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of @roop's answer.

```
QPixmap pixmap(mywidget.sizeHint());
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
mywidget.render(&painter);
pixmap.save("/some/file.png");
```

Changes:

- using pixmap instead of image
- using size hint instead of size
- saving to lossless PNG instead of JPEG

Note that for this to work, the widget does NOT need to be displayed on screen.